# UIImageView with strange behaviours with DownArrow.png

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uiimageview, interface-builder

I have an image under Resources group named "DownArrow.png"

- Open your viewController.xib
- Drag & drop an imageview
- select imageview & press command+1 ( for attribute inspector )
- now set image name DownArrow.png
- save your viewController.xib
- close it
- now reopen it.
- you will find imageview with different image ( which is really a downArrow )
- imageView image name property will have now "DownArrow" only instead of "DownArrow.png"

I am using iPhone SDK 3.2
When you run your program, you want be able to see that image.

Edit:

- Just drag & drop UIImageView into your viewController.xib
- Now set the imagename property to only "DownArrow"
- Remove Opaque checkmark
- You will see a down arrow in image view - but not while executing program.
- Similarly, I found working "RightArrow", "LeftArrow", "TopArrow" & "DownArrow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really is strange, and it's the first I've heard of this. Looks like DownArrow is a reserved name, at least for IB.

**UPDATE:**

Further inspection revealed that the image you see is actually the DownArrow.png included in Interface Builder's own bundle. I'm guessing you will see the same thing with any file name from `/Developer/Applications/Interface Builder.app/Contents/Resources`

This is obviously a bug in IB, and needs to be reported on Radar.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've reported it on Radar: rdar://8199687 - http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=463403